# Can Unicorn handle HTTPS requests directly (without the request going through Apache/Nginx)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, unicorn

I'm sure many will consider this a dumb question but I can't find a straight answer anywhere on the web:

Can Unicorn be configured to handle HTTPS requests directly, without reverse-proxying the request through another web server such as Apache or Nginx? (And if so, how?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicorn is optimized to handle fast connections and is not meant to be used for direct client communication. If you consider using https I would assume that your are transferring data through an potentially uncontrollable line. It's better to use another web server for terminating the ssl connection.

Comment: Understood, but I'd like to know: is it possible to do this? And how?

Comment: OK, it seems like there is really no way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: One valid reason for using SSL on 'dev servers' like Unicorn & Webrick is for testing payment gateway integration, where the return URL is forced to be on HTTPS.